# regex: capture only the second occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex to extract the second occurrence of matches in javascript.
My intended extract is "attributes_" located right after "root_first_attributes_0_second_".
Please refer to my code snippet below for an example.

```
template = "root_first_attributes_0_second_attributes_0_third_attributes_0_third_name"

my regex
==========
var n = template.match(/(attributes[_\]\[]+)\d+/g)
```

My composed regex doesn't work the way I wanted, as it's returning all occurrences of the matching pattern, meaning three of them returned.

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: probably the cleanest solution is to simply take the second match returned.

Comment: If you want the second one, just pick it: `var n = template.match(/(attributes[_\]\[]+)\d+/g)[1]`

Comment: something like this: `(?:(attributes[_\]\[]+)\d+(?:.*?)){2}` ? http://www.regex101.com/r/sI0lK5

Answer (score 2):

## Description

Consider the following powershell example of a regex which should work in javascript (or it did for me on http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm. The regex group return $1 will contain the value substring in the attributes area of the second option.  I did modify your source text to illustrate that this will also find underbars inside the attribute substring.

`^.*?_0_[^_]*[_](.*?)(_0_|$)`

## Example

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'root_first_attributes_0_second_Attributes_ToVoteFor_0_third_attributes_0_third_name'
Write-Host start with 
write-host $String
Write-Host
Write-Host found
([regex]'^.*?_0_[^_]*[_](.*?)(_0_|$)').matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "key at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    } # next match
```

## Yields

start with:
`root_first_attributes_0_second_Attributes_ToVoteFor_0_third_attributes_0_third_name`

found
key at 31 = 'Attributes_ToVoteFor'

## Summary

- `^` from the start of the string
- `.*?` move through the least number of characters to reach
- `_0_` the first delimiter
- `[^_]*` then move through the next non-underbar characters
- `[_]` until you read the first underbar
- `(.*?)` capture and return all characters before
- `(_0_|$)` the next delimiter or end of string

## Extra Credit

To capture the attributes field for the X'th group in the list, you could modify regex by making the non-greedy search into a non-capture block followed by count. These can be tested at [www.pcreck.com/JavaScript/advanced](http://www.pcreck.com/NnliZnhzN3g5MmZ0MTZibA==)

- `^(?:.*?_0_){0}[^_]*[_](.*?)(?=_0_|$)` matches the `first_attributes`
- `^(?:.*?_0_){1}[^_]*[_](.*?)(?=_0_|$)` matches the `Attributes_ToVoteFor`
- `^(?:.*?_0_){2}[^_]*[_](.*?)(?=_0_|$)` matches the `attributes`
- `^(?:.*?_0_){3}[^_]*[_](.*?)(?=_0_|$)` matches the `name`